# Variable can't hold str() method information with "pure" word in brackets... why?

Tags: python, variables, strings, methods

I've recently bumped into string methods and mainly

```
str()
```

method caught my interest because, it makes string out of every type of data?
integers, booleans and so on. And if you want, they can be easily stored in variables like new strings:

```
my_string = str(45161516)
```

that variable will automatically hold that number as a string and same with the boolean:

```
my_string = str(True)
```

but, when you put pure word "dog" for example:

```
my_string = str(dog)
```

variable won't hold it as a string... Here's also an image when I was trying out this concept during my Python course:

[image]

Can I ask why is it so?

Why the variable doesn't return value and why

```
str(dog)
```

doesn't make a string "dog"?

Is it because "dog" in no datatype so the method doesn't recognize it?

Or it's just way it is and don't poke the beehive.
At first I thought that variables can't hold string methods but it turned out that

```
my_variable = str(pure word)
```

is the only case when variable doesn't hold and return anything.

Comment: You can't get the string value of something that doesn't exist. `dog` doesn't exist until you set it to something.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been downvoted to -3. It's a very basic question, but it's not a *bad* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is not valid python. A string literal has to be defined in one of the following ways.

```
str1 = "test"
str2 = 'test2'
str3 = """test3"""
```

Comment: So, are you telling me that I'm working in a program that doesn't even have similar rules as a real Python and is just a substitute of it?                      Because, that would mean that I'm learning nonsense :D that has no real application later on...

Comment: I don't follow. Learn about strings of the "real" python https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: @Jakub No, that's not what Esben is saying. The pieces of code `str(45161516)` and `str(True)` are valid Python.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, when you call a function with an argument, that argument must always be a valid expression. The pieces of code `45161516` and `True` are valid expressions, but `dog` is not a valid expression (if it has not been defined anywhere). So you cannot use `dog` in a function argument if `dog` has not been defined.

It probably *looks* like the `str` method creates a string out of whatever text you type between the parentheses, but this is not actually how `str` works at all.

Here is how Python evaluates `str(45161516)`:

- First, Python evaluates the expression `str` to obtain a function. The function that it obtains is the "str" function.
- Then, Python evaluates the expression `45161516` to obtain an argument. The argument that it obtains is the number 45161516.
- Python calls the function (which is the "str" function) with the argument (which is the number 45161516) and obtains a result. The result is the character string "45161516".

And here's how Python evaluates `str(True)`:

- First, Python evaluates the expression `str` to obtain a function. The function that it obtains is the "str" function.
- Then, Python evaluates the expression `True` to obtain an argument. The argument that it obtains is the boolean value "true".
- Python calls the function (which is the "str" function) with the argument (which is the boolean value "true") and obtains a result. The result is the character string "True".

Finally, here's how Python tries to evaluate `str(dog)`:

- First, Python evaluates the expression `str` to obtain a function. The function that it obtains is the "str" function.
- Then, Python attempts to evaluate the expression `dog` to obtain an argument. However, the expression `dog` does not have a value (if it has not been defined), so the evaluation fails.

Of course, you can define a variable called `dog` if you want. You can run this code:

```
dog = 12345
print str(dog)
```

Since the value of the variable `dog` is the number 12345, when Python evaluates the expression `dog` to obtain an argument, the argument that obtains will be the number 12345. So the result of the "str" function will be the character string "12345", and this string will be printed.

Comment: "However, the expression dog does not have a value": You could expand on this and say that it is parsed and evaluated as a variable name, and **not** as a string literal, as the OP seems to imply in their question.